# Escape test parameter value in Test Professional 2015

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, microsoft-test-manager

I need to have the tester enter "@SomeValue" but it is automatically creating a parameter named "SomeValue". I do not want to create a parameter, how can I escape the @ symbol? I have tried the normal backslash escape character but it does not work.

Comment: This is the parameter given in steps and '@' annotation is used to recognize parameters passed. Try using "@@SomeValue", this would ignore the first '@' and consider the remaining string as a parameter input.
Ensure that you read the parameter as String in the method you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced similar issues. As far as I know, there is no correct way to to escape the automatic parameter creation.

But there are some workarounds you could work with.

- put a space between the '@' and the name
- put a letter (or some symbols) before the '@' like it is in email adresses
- or live with the empty parameter, but this will be visible in the Test Runner

This is how they look in Test Runner:

[image]

I hope one of these workaround fits your needs.

Best regards

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion as you have. It is unfortunate that they don't have a proper way to escape an @ character...